# File Upload Return Value

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

So I have learned that when a file is uploaded in Drupal, you get the `fid` in return, which you can find in the files table in the database. I keep seeing strings that look like the following, and I was hoping someone could explain each part.

```
a:2:{i:0;s:4:"9201";i:1;s:4:"9206";}
```

I can see that here the fids are 9201 and 9206, respectively, and I'm assuming the `i:0` and `i:1` have to do with the order the files were uploaded. But what is the rest of it?

Also, if it matters, this particular string was the result of a print_r from form data with a multi-file upload field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the return value from PHP's [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) function when passed an array equivalent to the following:

```
array(
  0 => "9201",
  1 => "9206"
)
```

You can reverse the process using [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

Drupal (like a lot of applications) saves some settings in a serialized string rather than creating database tables for every possible setting.

**EDIT**

Just to add, `a:2` means the type of variable to follow is an array with 2 elements and `s:4` means the type of variable is a string with 4 characters. `i` denotes an integer type.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! So is there anything more to the a:2 and s:4 parts?

Comment: @RodneyKeeling: Forgot about that, I've updated the answer :)